# How to update a column in one table based on values from a second table?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery

Given the following two tables in a PostgreSQL database ...

Table `observation`:

```
+---------------+---------+
| observationid | deleted | 
+---------------+---------+
|      1        |    F    |
|      2        |    F    |
|      3        |    F    |
+---------------+---------+
```

Table `numericvalue`:

```
+---------------+-------+
| observationid | value | 
+---------------+-------+
|       1       |  999  |
|       2       |   5   |
|       3       |  999  |
+---------------+-------+
```

I want to set the value of column `deleted` to `'T'` in all rows in `observation` whenever the associated row in `numericvalue` contains the `value` equal to `999`.

The `SELECT` query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM observation o
INNER JOIN numericvalue n
ON o.observationid = n.observationid
AND n.value = 999;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE observation ob
SET deleted = 'T'
FROM numericvalue nv
WHERE nv.value = 999
AND nv.observationid = ob.observationid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE observation
SET deleted = 'T'
WHERE observationid IN (SELECT observationid FROM numericvalue WHERE value=999)
```